# React Native app data storage to Google drive and iCloud

Tags: react-native, google-drive-api, icloud, keychain, public-key-encryption

I am trying to store my app data on Google Drive and iCloud based on user device.I don't want to use Async Storage ,redux state neither I want to store data on my server cloud i.e. AWS. Basically I like the way  how WhatsApp takes data backup on google drive for android devices and iCloud for IOS devices.This way I want to store my encrypted data's private keys on drive or iCloud so that if user changes his device I can get these keys from drive or iCloud and proceed for decryption mechanism.I found https://github.com/manicakes/react-native-icloudstore which serves my purpose for iCloud.But I haven't found anything on same line for google drive.Can you please suggest me better approach for above requirement?

Answer (score 0):

For Google Drive Implementation You can Check this Package : [react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@robinbobin/react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper)  . You Have To Use Google SignIn With this package In order Get the Access Token , Install This Package Also  [react-native-google-signin/google-signin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin) .

A Quick Example :

```
  import { GoogleSignin } from "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin";
import {
  GDrive,
  ListQueryBuilder,
  MimeTypes
} from "@robinbobin/react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper";
import React, {
  useCallback,
  useEffect,
  useState
} from "react";
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Button,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet
} from "react-native";
import { name } from './app.json';

function App() {
  const [gdrive] = useState(() => new GDrive());
  const [ui, setUi] = useState();
  
  const invoker = useCallback(async cb => {
    try {
      return await cb();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, []);
  
  const createBinaryFile = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log(await invoker(async () => (
      await gdrive.files.newMultipartUploader()
        .setData([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], MimeTypes.BINARY)
        .setRequestBody({
          name: "bin",
          //parents: ["folder_id"]
        })
        .execute()
    )));
  }, [invoker]);
  
  const createIfNotExists = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log(await invoker(async () => (
      await gdrive.files.createIfNotExists(
        {
          q: new ListQueryBuilder()
            .e("name", "condition_folder")
            .and()
            .e("mimeType", MimeTypes.FOLDER)
            .and()
            .in("root", "parents")
        },
        gdrive.files.newMetadataOnlyUploader()
          .setRequestBody({
            name: "condition_folder",
            mimeType: MimeTypes.FOLDER,
            parents: ["root"]
          })
        )
    )));
  }, [invoker]);
  
  const createFolder = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log(await invoker(async () => (
      await gdrive.files.newMetadataOnlyUploader()
        .setRequestBody({
          name: "Folder",
          mimeType: MimeTypes.FOLDER,
          parents: ["root"]
        })
        .execute()
    )));
  }, [invoker]);
  
  const createTextFile = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log(await invoker(async () => {
      return (await gdrive.files.newMultipartUploader()
        .setData("cm9iaW4=", MimeTypes.TEXT)
        .setIsBase64(true)
        .setRequestBody({
          name: "base64 text",
        })
        .execute()).id;
    }));
  }, [invoker]);
  
  const emptyTrash = useCallback(async () => {
    if (await invoker(async () => {
      await gdrive.files.emptyTrash();
      
      return true;
    }))
    {
      console.log("Trash emptied");
    };
  }, [invoker]);
  
  const getWebViewLink = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log(await invoker(async () => (
      await gdrive.files.getMetadata(
        "some_id", {
          fields: "webViewLink"
        }
      )
    )));
  }, [invoker]);
  
  const readFiles = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log(await invoker(async () => (
      await gdrive.files.getText("text_file_id")
    )));
    
    console.log(await invoker(async () => (
      await gdrive.files.getBinary("bin_file_id", null, "1-1")
    )))
  }, [invoker]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      scopes: [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appfolder"
      ]});
    
    (async () => {
      if (await invoker(async () => {
        await GoogleSignin.signIn();
        
        gdrive.accessToken = (await GoogleSignin.getTokens()).accessToken;
        
        gdrive.files.fetchCoercesTypes = true;
        gdrive.files.fetchRejectsOnHttpErrors = true;
        gdrive.files.fetchTimeout = 1500;
        
        return true;
      }))
      {
        setUi([
          ["create bin file", createBinaryFile],
          ["create folder", createFolder],
          ["create if not exists", createIfNotExists],
          ["create text file", createTextFile],
          ["empty trash", emptyTrash],
          ["get webViewLink", getWebViewLink],
          ["read files", readFiles]
        ].map(([title, onPress], index) => (
          <Button
            key={index}
            onPress={onPress}
            title={title}
          />
        )));
      }
    })();
  }, [
    createBinaryFile,
    createFolder,
    createIfNotExists,
    createTextFile,
    emptyTrash,
    getWebViewLink,
    readFiles,
    invoker
  ]);
  
  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={styles.container}
    >
      {ui}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "cyan",
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    padding: 25
  }
});
```